# I am getting an error - no module named for Import ta-lib in Python on Mac

Tags: python, ta-lib

I  am getting the following error in Jupyter Note Book when running the code below in Python.

```
import talib
```

I get the following

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-29b7d6c547d4> in <module>()
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import tensorflow
----> 6 import talib
      7 import _talib
      8 import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi

ImportError: No module named 'talib'
```

I am running Anaconda on a MAC

I have looked at all of the existing questions on this and found nothing.

When I use the PIP freeze command I see the following library and version
TA-Lib==0.4.17

The folder talib exists in the following path
anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Comment: Try to run `! pip freeze` from the notebook

Comment: Thanks - I tried !pip freeze from notebook no Talib in the list, I tried running import talib in the terminal prompt worked fine - so the problem is all in Jupyter somehow need to get Talib package in the notebook -  any guidance would be great?

Comment: Are you using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)?